# Compensate system sleep for scheduled tasks?

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, scheduler, scheduling

I wrote a simple proof-of-concept for scheduling a runnable to execute at a given time. The code works exactly as expected and executes the runnable at the scheduled time:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    Runnable task = () -> System.out.println("Task Ran @ " + formatter.format(LocalDateTime.now()));

    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    LocalDateTime runTime = ciel(ChronoUnit.MINUTES, now.plusMinutes(1));

    Duration duration = Duration.between(now, runTime);
    long initialDelay = duration.toMillis();

    System.out.println("Schedule @ " + formatter.format(now));
    System.out.println("Expected @ " + formatter.format(runTime));
    scheduler.schedule(task, initialDelay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    scheduler.shutdown();
    scheduler.awaitTermination(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
}

private static LocalDateTime ciel(TemporalUnit precision, LocalDateTime time) {
    return time.truncatedTo(precision).plus(1, precision);
}
```

Output:

```
Schedule @ 12/18/2023 11:31:47 AM
Expected @ 12/18/2023 11:33:00 AM
Task Ran @ 12/18/2023 11:33:00 AM
```

However, if I put the system to sleep while the program is running and proceed to wake it later, the runnable will be executed outside of the scheduled time:

```
Schedule @ 12/18/2023 11:35:53 AM
Expected @ 12/18/2023 11:37:00 AM
Task Ran @ 12/18/2023 11:39:13 AM
```

Assuming the OS wakes before the scheduled time, how can I compensate for this so the runnable is still executed when expected?

Comment: What options does the OS provide?  Lucid dreaming mode?

Comment: @AndrewS ideally, the solution will be platform independent.

Comment: This appears to be issue [JDK-8146527](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8146527), still unresolved after nearly 8 years.  You'll probably need to use something other than a `ScheduledExecutorService` to work around it.

Comment: By the way, `LocalDateTime` is the wrong type to use here as it lacks the context of an offset or time zone. Use `Instant`, `OffsetDateTime`, or `ZonedDateTime`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I suggest you make an Answer of your Comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I noted in comments, the issue you observe with a system suspend / sleep delaying execution of tasks scheduled via a `ScheduledExecutorService` appears to be known issue [JDK-8146527](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8146527), originally filed at the beginning of 2016.  There doesn't appear to be any workaround available from `ScheduledExecutorService` or its standard implementation `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`.

However, you might be able to work around it via a different scheduling mechanism, such as [`java.util.Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Timer.html).  Moreover, that particular class offers a built-in method for [scheduling execution at a particular point in time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Timer.html#schedule(java.util.TimerTask,java.util.Date)), so that you should not need to compute a delay yourself if you don't already have one.  If you choose to use a `Timer` then you should be sure to read and understand the caveats expressed in its docs.  That might look like so:

```
import java.util.Timer;  // Do not confuse this with javax.swing.Timer
// ...

public static void main(String[] args) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Task Ran @ " + formatter.format(ZonedDateTime.now()));
            timer.cancel();
        }
    };
    ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now();
    ZonedDateTime runTime = now.plusMinutes(1);

    System.out.println("Schedule @ " + formatter.format(now));
    System.out.println("Expected @ " + formatter.format(runTime));
    timer.schedule(task, Date.from(runTime.toInstant()));
}
```

That method works for scheduling a task at a specified time, but I have no good means to test it in the specific case of a system suspend.  If it doesn't solve that issue then you probably need to find a third-party scheduler that can handle it, or else write your own.

Comment: Side note: the `timer.cancel()` call was necessary for me to make the program terminate cleanly, presumably because the timer's thread was not shutting down automatically. At least, not in the amount of time I was willing to wait.  Under other circumstances, you might not want that, or maybe not there, in the task.